# How can I only retrieve rows with dates greater than today's date from an XML column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I want to only return rows that have a date in the XML column after the current date in SQL Server. How can i do this?

The error i receive for the last line below is: **XQuery [LB_Webinar.WebinarXML.exist()]: There is no function '{http://www.w3.org/2004/07/xpath-functions}:GETDATE()'**

```
(
   @Site varchar(10)
)

AS

WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.testsite.com/ClientWebinar' as lbx)

SELECT * FROM LB_Webinar 

WHERE

Site = @Site

AND

LB_Webinar.WebinarXML.exist('/lbx:CLIENT_WEBINAR/lbx:WEBINAR/lbx:WEBINARDATE > GETDATE()') = 1
```

XML Code:

```
<lbx:CLIENT_WEBINAR xmlns:lbx="http://www.testsite.com/ClientWebinar">
    <lbx:WEBINAR>
        <lbx:WEBINARDATE>6/18/2013 2:00:00 PM</lbx:WEBINARDATE>
    </lbx:WEBINAR>
</lbx:CLIENT_WEBINAR>
```

Comment: Is there any chance you could change the representation of the datetime value in your XML to use ISO8601 datetime format `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm`?

Comment: @Mikael, yes i can definitely do that.

Comment: Good, that is the way `datetime` values should be [represented in XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store today's `datetime` value in a variable and use `sql:variable()` in your expression to use the variable in the comparison.

```
DECLARE @Today DATETIME;
SET @Today = GETDATE();

WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.testsite.com/ClientWebinar' as lbx)
SELECT *
FROM LB_Webinar 
WHERE LB_Webinar.WebinarXML.exist('/lbx:CLIENT_WEBINAR/lbx:WEBINAR/lbx:WEBINARDATE/text()[. > sql:variable("@Today")]') = 1;
```

Note: the above code works if you change your `datetime` values to ISO8601 `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm`.